# Java: Json determine depth level

Tags: java, json

Hey guys I am receiving a Json with JSONArrays that contain JSONArrays - practically a tree structure. I am parsing it all nice and well but I want to know the exact depth of the arrays I receive.

For example:

if i get X elements and each of the X elements contain Y elements and each Y element contains Z elements and etc. I want to know what is the depth level of the Y elements? Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Each element contains the same stuff?

Comment: yes they all contain strings